# Why does left-shifting an integer by 24-bit yield the wrong result?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I tried left-shifting a 32-bit integer by 24:

```
char *int_to_bin(int num) {
    int i = 0;
    static char bin[64];
   
    while (num != 0) {
        bin[i] = num % 2 + 48;
        num /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    bin[i] = '\0';
    return (bin);
}

int main() {
    int number = 255;
    printf("number: %s\n", int_to_bin(number));
    printf("shifted number: %s\n", int_to_bin(number << 24));
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
number: 11111111
shifted number: 000000000000000000000000/
```

and i left-shift with 23-bit it yields this result:

```
0000000000000000000000011111111
```

Well Why is it like that and what's the matter with '/' at the end of the wrong result?

Comment: try adding parentheses around `num % 2` and use `'0'` instead of `48` for clarity. Also `num & 1` is more common than `num % 2` to get the value of the lsb. Also recommend using `uint32_t` from `stdint.h` instead of `int`

Comment: @vicatcu The precedence of the operator ```%``` is greater than that of ```+``` so it doesn't matter nor it affects the result!

Comment: You should also pass the bin buffer into the function rather than returning a local static variable. You could also say `num >>= 1` instead of `num /= 2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

- If `number` has the value 255 then `number << 24` has the numerical value 4278190080, which overflows a 32-bit signed integer whose largest possible value is 2147483647.  Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C, so the result could be anything at all.

  What probably happens in this case is that the result of the shift is negative.  When `num` is negative then `num % 2` may take the value `-1`, so you store character 47 in the string, which is `/`.

  Bit shifting math is usually better to do with `unsigned` types, where overflow is well-defined (it wraps around and bits just shift off the left and vanish) and `num % 2` can only be 0 or 1.  (Or write `num & 1` instead.)
- Your `int_to_bin` routine puts the least-significant bits at the beginning of the string (on the left), so the result is backwards from the way people usually write numbers (with the least-significant bits on the right).  You may want to rewrite it.

Comment: @prog-fh `num & 1` is the wrong functionality when `num < 0` and the all but-obsolete ones' complement is used.

Comment: *`num % 2` can only be 0 or 1* Are you sure? https://godbolt.org/z/bjxxvY5vr

Comment: @0___________: That sentence is about **unsigned** types.

Answer (score 3):

Shift works fine, you simply print it from the wrong direction.

```
char *int_to_bin(char *buff, int num)
{
    unsigned mask = 1U << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(num) - 1);
    char *wrk = buff;
    for(; mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        *wrk++ = '0' + !!((unsigned)num & mask);
    }
    *wrk = 0;
    return buff;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 1];
    int number = 255;
    printf("number: %s\n", int_to_bin(buff, number));
    printf("shifted number: %s\n", int_to_bin(buff, number << 24));
    return 0;
}
```

Shifting signed integers left is OK, but the right shift is implementation-defined. Many systems use arithmetic shift right and the result is not the same as using the bitwise one:

https://godbolt.org/z/e7f3shxd4

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica does it make any difference for the compile-time constant if it will be 1UL or 1U instead?

Comment: For consistency, you should define `char buff[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 1];`

Comment: The OP's code is incorrect indeed, not just because of the endianness issue, but technically, `255 << 24` has undefined behavior on 32-bit systems.

Comment: @chqrlie C standard wise it is undefined.

Comment: That's what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you are storing numbers backwards
2. you are using signed int32 while shifting by 23 results needs more than 32 bits to handle that operation ...you should use long long int
3. signed integer can lead to wrong answers as 1<<31 is -1 which results in bad characters  in string
   finally using unsigned long long int with storing numbers in correct order will produce correct string
4. you should try re write code on your own before seeing this improved version of your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *int_to_bin( unsigned long long   int num) {
    int i = 0;
    static char bin[65];


    while (i != 64) {
        bin[63-i] = num % 2 + 48;
        num /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    bin[64] = '\0';

    return (bin);
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long  int number = 255;
    printf("number 1: %s\n", int_to_bin(number));
    printf("number 2: %s\n", int_to_bin(number << 24));
    return 0;
}
```

[image]