# A C left shift anomaly in unsigned long long ints

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

When this code:

```c
// Print out the powers of 2 from 1 to 63. 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned long long n = 64;
  for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned long long po2 = (1 << i);
    printf("%llu) %llu/%0llX\n", i, po2, po2);
  }
  printf("Size of unsigned long long int: %ld.\n", sizeof(unsigned long long int));
}
```

is run, left shift values up to 30 are correct:

```
1) 2/2
2) 4/4
3) 8/8
...
28) 268435456/10000000
29) 536870912/20000000
30) 1073741824/40000000
```

However, once `i == 31` (a 32 bit left shift), the results are not correct:

```
31) 18446744071562067968/FFFFFFFF80000000
32) 1/1
33) 2/2
34) 4/4
35) 8/8
36) 16/10
37) 32/20
...  
61) 536870912/20000000
62) 1073741824/40000000
63) 18446744071562067968/FFFFFFFF80000000  
Size of unsigned long long int: 8.
```

This is run on a 64 bit machine, and the C Standard states:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
> the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
> of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Note that the variables, `i` and `n`, in the above code are both 64 bit integers, yet they are treated as if they were 32 bit integers!

Comment: duplicates: [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714), [C left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048047/995714), [Why does left-shifting an integer by 24-bit yield the wrong result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70237047/995714), [Compute signed long max value in C using bit shift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41418472/995714), [C code not output the right number for long long int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59004225/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048047/c-left-shift-on-64-bits-fail)

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `<<` operation in the following line:

```c
unsigned long long po2 = (1 << i);
```

What is its ***left operand***? Well, that is the `int` literal, `1`, and an `int` type will *not* undergo promotion, in that context<sup>1</sup>. So, the type of the result will be `int`, as specified in the extract from the Standard that you cited, and that `int` result will be converted to the required `unsigned long long` type … but *after* the overflow (undefined behaviour) has already happened.

To fix the issue, make that literal an `unsigned long long`, using the `uLL` suffix:

```c
unsigned long long po2 = (1uLL << i);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Some clarity on the "context" from [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### Shift Operators
>
> …
> First, integer promotions are performed, ***individually, on each operand*** (Note: this is unlike
> other binary arithmetic operators, which all perform usual arithmetic
> conversions). The type of the result is the type of *lhs* after
> promotion.

Answer (score -1):

Adrian Mole is correct. The revised code:

```
// Print out the powers of 2 from 1 to 63. 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned long long n = 64,
                     one = 1;
  for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned long long po2 = (one << i);
    printf("%llu) %llu/%0llX\n", i, po2, po2);
  }
  printf("Size of unsigned long long int: %ld.\n", sizeof(unsigned long long int));
}
```

works.

Comment: This could be a comment. But the Right Way (TM) is to mark Andrian's answer. Please do so and remove this one.